# Grab list of Stats, Application Data, and Serials off OSX 10.6 to prepare for reformat and fresh install?

Tags: snow-leopard, disk-format, serial-number, system-information

I need to reformat my 2007 OSX as it is now returning kernal errors. I want to install everything fresh but I have a lot of software and don't want to sit here making a list of everything installed as it is all unorganized.

For windows I usually accomplish this with Belarc Advisor: http://download.cnet.com/Belarc-Advisor/3000-2094_4-10007277.html?tag=mncol;1

Is there something similar, whether a method or an app that will allow me to do this on a mac?

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you need (i.e. hardware, network information, software etc. thats similar to what Belarc Advisor returns) can be obtained using the built-in **System Profiler** application (`/Applications/Utilities/System Profiler.app`).

You can then export the information to a file using File ➔ Save As.., then select either "Plain Text" or "Rich Text Format" from the "File Format" dropdown.

The above can get quite verbose, so if you just want a quick snapshot of installed apps (including those installed by default, of course), you could start the Terminal (`/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`) then type

`ls /Applications`

or

`ls /Applications > ~/Documents/apps.txt` to send the output to the file `apps.txt` in your Documents folder.